# How much capacity is left in my channel?

Tags: go, channel

Is there a way to see how much storage is left in my asynchronous channel in Go?

For example

```
a chan uint=make(chan bool, 5)
a<-true
fmt.Printf(a.capazity())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make(chan bool, 5)
    a <- true
    fmt.Println(cap(a) - len(a))
}
```

Output:

```
4
```